# Convert .gsm to mp3 using C# or Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, api, video.js

I am going to develop a application for QA and need to convert .gsm file to compatible web based format with 2-6 hours length.

I wanna know about How i can convert .gsm file to HTML5 compatible audio formate.

Comment: Alright then, best of luck! Let us know if you have any coding questions once you start your project.

Comment: Actually i am working but HTML 5 player not compatible to play .gsm format so first i need to convert my file extension to wav, mp3 or any supported format have you any idea how i can convert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my question after R&D.

Using ***[Sox](http://sox.sourceforge.net/)*** Utility

Use C# code for exucute ***[Sox](http://sox.sourceforge.net/)*** cmd utily from appliction

> sox input.gsm -r 8000 -c 1 -w -s ouput.wav